# How to make a sql query with variables work from php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

This query works when run from the command line (sqlcmd). I can't figure out how to make it work within a php script.

```
exec sp_executesql N'select N2."Name" from (("dbo"."BasicAnimal" N0 left join "dbo"."AnimalGroup" N1 on (N0."Group" = N1."OID")) left join "dbo"."AbstractGroup" N2 on (N1."OID" = N2."OID"))where (N0."GCRecord" is null and (((N0."IsCulled" = @p0) and N0."ExitDate" is null) or (not (N0."Group" is null) and N0."ExitDate" is null)))',N'@p0 nvarchar(8)',@p0=N'False'
go
```

If I swap out the above query from the php script with something basic like:

```
select * from dbo.AnimalGroup
```

it works...

The problem is that the query itself contains single and double quotes so I can't created a php variable like:

```
$sql='query goes here'
```

or

```
$sql="query goes here"
```

Comment: Have a look at the examples in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: ...what errors are you getting with the top query when you run it through PHP? You might have to rewrite it to be more friendly

Comment: every time someone forgets to use Markdown, John Gruber dies a little inside, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Comment: I know it's an extremely ugly query. I had to use a db trace program to capture it. I am new to sql and it was the only way I could figure out how to get the info I need out of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$sql = 'single "dobuble"  \' again single quotes\' '
```

Comment: Thank you. Escaping the single quotes contained within the query gives me this error:  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'go'.

Comment: No, it didn't work. It errors out saying " incorrect syntax near 'go'"

Comment: Okay that is the only alternative, I cant help yo anymore.

Comment: `GO` is not a valid SQL Statement, it is a batch separator, you should remove it from your query when executing in PHP and it will work.